# Connect MySQl with Python Error : function 'inet_pton' not found

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

```
import mysql.connector

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password,host=host,database=database)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    add_employee = ("INSERT INTO tbl_gps "
    "(Locating, MainPower, Acc, PowerOff, Alarm,Speed,Direction,Latitude,Longitude,DateTime,IOState,OilState,MainID) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,% s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, (SELECT MainID From tbl_device WHERE DeviceID = %s))")
    data_employee = {
                  'Locating': 1,
                  'MainPower': 1,
                  'Acc': 1,
                  'PowerOff': 1,
                  'Alarm': 0x80,
                  'Speed': 1,
                  'Direction': 300,
                  'Latitude': 10.00,
                  'Longtitude': -20.00,
                  'DateTime': '2013/2/8 01:00:00',
                  'IOState': 0,
                  'OilState': 0,
                  'MainID': 'NR09533'
                }
    cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
    cnx.close()
```

when i debug get the following error:

```
AttributeError: function 'inet_pton' not found
```

what wrong with my code?please help to fix it,thanks you very much !
the connector are downlaoded from Mysql official web site,
and i m using Python 3.3
i have found this in google, this is a Mysql Bug?because i m using Window XP.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved after i download the Connector from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python, the mysql official web's connector can't use

Answer (score 0):

oh, that hits the point, i came across the same problem. thanks, it really works. 
it seems the privous version(1.0.7) is ok, and v1.0.8 is bad.

ps. the real download link is:
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.7.zip

the installation tutorial is in dir 'doc'.